Self-hosted agent DevOps pipeline build verification task failing because of Powershell execution policy
Hi I have a DevOps pipeline which has the following steps
Initialize Job --> Checkout Solution --> Checkout templates --> Restore Packages --> Versioning --> Build Solutions --> Unit Test --> Collect Artifacts --> Build Verification --> Pack Artificats --> Publish CI Artifacts --> Pack Pipeline Artifacts  etc...
Initially it was failing on the step **Build Solutions (VSBuild@1) ** with error like
*.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy
Changing execution policy at Current User or Local machine level is not working, it works only if I change the Machine policy with below command
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -Name ExectionPolicy -Value ByPass (or RemoteSighed)

However, this gets over-written after some time by group policy updates and our IT is reluctant to change the Machine Policy permanently.
So, I fixed this error by signing all the scripts in C:\agent_Work parent directory. Now this step working fine.
I am now getting same error on Build Verification step. In this step we are running a PowerShell@2 task with the below script
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Build Verification'
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['System.Debug'], 'true'))
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Get-ChildItem "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" -Recurse

This step is creating some temporary script files at run time and gives error like

**Generating script.
##[debug]AGENT_VERSION: '3.236.1'
##[debug]AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY: 'C:\agent\agent01_work_temp'
##[debug]Asserting container path exists: 'C:\agent\agent01_work_temp'
##[debug]Asserting leaf path exists: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
##[debug] Arguments: '-NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\agent01\_work\_temp\879635e3-95db-4615-a7ae-107db204cdef.ps1'"'
##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'C:\agent\agent01\_work\17\s' "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo
-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\agent01_work_temp\879635e3-95db-4615-a7ae-107db204cdef.ps1'"
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: C:\ Available 46746.00 MB out of 129481.00 MB, Memory: Used 3836.00 MB out of 8190.00 MB, CPU:
Usage 9.07% . : File
C:\agent\agent01\_work\_temp\879635e3-95db-4615-a7ae-107db204cdef.ps1
cannot be loaded. The file
C:\agent\agent01\_work\_temp\879635e3-95db-4615-a7ae-107db204cdef.ps1
is not digitally signed. You cannot run this  script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting
execution policy, see  about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

**
File name is like [guid].ps1 and this guid keeps changing every time the pipeline runs. and these temp files cannot be seen physically.
How can I sign these files at run time.
I even tried removing this step completed, however it fails on the step "Pack Pipeline Artifacts" with similar error as above. Even in this step some temporary PowserShell script files are getting generated, this step also runs the below PowerShell@2 task
- task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'Pack Pipeline Artifacts'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Artifact" | out-null

Please help I have run out of all options.
Thanks a lot in advance

Based on your YAML sample, I can reproduce the same issue when using the PowerShell task to execute the commands.

The newly .ps1 file in temp folder will be generated and run instantly.
In this case the method of signing all .ps1 files will not apply because the file is different in each run and cannot be obtained and signed ahead of time.
Currently, I'm afraid we can only alleviate this issue by setting Machine Policy to ByPass.
The reason why settings Current User or Local machine are invalid is that they will be overwritten by Machine Policy level settings. Refer to this doc: Execution policy scope
When Machine Policy is AllSigned, we can only alleviate it by signing all powershell files or setting Machine Policy ByPass.
Under the current situation, we can only regularly update the Machine Policy to byPass to make the Pipeline run normally.

Thanks Kevin, its true there is no other way, we are trying to convince our IT or every time we run pipeline we have to set machine policy like I mentioned in my post.
